# Warning: Comparison between pointer and integer and escape characters

Tags: c

1)I tested my code on https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php
It somehow works by showing the ideal output of 1,3,27,23,19 but gives me the error message too which is strange since all my functions didn't have any integers. Can anyone tell me why the line shown with the error is wrong?

2)I suspected it has to do with the character `'` not being handled properly, but I do not know how to print out all the special characters other than `%%` and `\\`. Can someone direct me to a full list of them?

Edit: I realised there's actually 2 escape characters I got wrong(found the proper term for it on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/escape-sequences-c/), which is both the single quote and double quote. Are there anymore other than this list?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int improvedCountWords(const char *str) {

    int size=0;
    int number=0;
    int length=0;
    while (str[size]!='\0'){
        if (str[size]==' ' || str[size]=='.' || str[size]=='\\' || str[size]=='*' || str[size]=='"'){
            if (length>0){
                number+=1;
                length=0;
            }

        }
        else if (str[size]=='-' || str[size]=="'"){
            if (length>0){
                length++;
            }

        }
        else{
            length++;
        }
        size++;
    }
    if (length>0){
        number++;
    }
    return number;
}


int main(){
    char s1[]="Panting heavily, he continues his exercises -- grepping, installing new packages, logging in as root, and writing replacements for two-year-old shell scripts in Python.";

    char s2[]="\" You'll know why Python is better than Perl... when you try to read your code *six* months from now ...\"";
    char s3[]="With Yoda strapped to his back, Luke climbs up one of the many thick vines that grow in the swamp until he reaches the Dagobah statistics lab.";

    int x1=improvedCountWords("Python");        
    int x2=improvedCountWords("Python is AWESOME");
    int x3=improvedCountWords(s3);
    int x4=improvedCountWords(s1);
    int x5=improvedCountWords(s2);


    printf("%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",x1,x2,x3,x4,x5);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apparently, you're a Python fan. But you can't use single quotes and double quotes interchangeably in C as you can in Python. Use `'\''`, not `"'"`.

Comment: @FredLarson actually this was a programming module taught in 80% Python and 20% C, so I had quite some difficulty transiting into the C phase looking at the syntax. There's alot of technical things like this that I need to know more about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str[size]` is a character and you are comparing it with string literal - `"'"` *[compiler must be giving a warning on this statement]*. Since you want to compare a character of string `str` with single quote `'` you need to escape it so that it does not represent itself. Use escape character `\` to do it. Hence it should be:

```
str[size]=='\''
```

*From C Standard#6.4.4.4p3*

> The single-quote ', the double-quote ", the question-mark ?, the backslash \, and arbitrary integer values are representable according to the following table of escape sequences:

```
   single quote '            \'
   double quote "            \"
   question mark ?           \?
   backslash \               \\
   octal character           \octal digits
   hexadecimal character     \x hexadecimal digits
```

Answer (score 5):

Your pointer is `"'"` and the int is the character value in `str[size]` being promoted in the `==` comparison.  It's in this line and it's not handled properly;

```
    else if (str[size]=='-' || str[size]=="'"){
```

You probably need to compare it with `'\''` like this;

```
    else if (str[size]=='-' || str[size]=='\''){
```